# SQL Server 2008 change tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to make schema change to SQL server 2008 internal change tracking tables ( I don't mind to put the database in single user mode on Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC) if required).

For Ex, I want to change a single column primary key to Composite primary Key on a User table, but i don't want to loose the change tracking data for that table. Is it possible to update the Change tracking table schema to include the composite key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you archive the change tracking data somewhere before you change the keys and re-initiate CT? If the columns can still line up, you can create a view that unions the two tables. Seems much simpler (never mind supported) to me.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. But the issue is that SQL server change tracking functions will return the change tracking data in correct fashion based on the anchor value passed into them. I cannot mimic that feature when i union the saved change tracking data with the data from change tracking tables.

So i was looking for ways to have direct control over change tracking tables.

Comment: Understood, and I'm afraid you'll either have to (a) retrieve the information from the union manually instead of using the functions, or (b) suffer the loss of the CT information. You could always take a backup now, restore it as a different name, then use the function against the old copy and union that with the results of the function against the current copy.